# JavaScript SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript

I have this code for a rock, paper, scissors game that is basically homework. I have double-checked and it seems to be fine, however, when I run it it says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else,
```

any help will be very appreciated :) Please note that I am a newbie, so if the question is dumb, please be nice and help <3

I just edited the code a bit, since I had many "Overlook" mistakes. I also wanted to clarify that I need all the code located after the `function` statement to be inside the function, that is why I don't close the first `{` right away.
PD: Now I get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();


if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2)
        return "The result is a tie!";
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
      } else if (choice1 ==== "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "scissors wins"; }

            else {
                return "Paper wins"; }    
            }
        }
}

compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

Comment: Indent your code correctly and look carefully at your braces.

Comment: You need to decide whether you're going to use curly braces with your conditions or not, because that's where the error is. I would suggest _always_ using them.

Comment: here is your error  `else if{`  at this block `if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins"
            else if{
                return "paper wins"
            }`

Comment: Well, that's at least _one_ of them.

Comment: Ok, @Juhana and I bet your parents injected all this knowledge into you when you were born, so you grew up knowing it. Unfortunately, I just started learning it and am so overwhelmed trying to find my errors that I overlooked many of them, and felt so frustrated that brought my code here, hoping to find nice people who would help me instead of laughing at me, but thanks, your comments helped me a bunch

Comment: @L.Gonzalez it is SO's way of hazing its new comers, don't beat yourself up about it. SO is a cesspool of negativity, with only a few kind and helpful people. (I am not one of the nice ones) anyways, you will learn that asking questions here come at a price, don't take it personal.

Comment: @L.Gonzalez, I've been on here a while and never seen Juhana be cruel. Think of it as a gentle ribbing rather than a mocking. SO can be a tough crowd sometimes and it takes a lot to come on here with a problem as a newcomer to both the site and coding. Don't be too disheartened if you get some knock-back. We're all here to help each other. Hopefully some of the suggestions here will help you in the long-term. Good luck with your coding, and Happy New Year too.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, SO is _not_ a cesspool - there are _loads_ of helpful people on here. Maybe, as an admittedly not-a-nice-guy, you got some knockback because of that and it's coloured your perception. Try not to be that guy, perhaps.

Comment: @Andy SO years ago was one thing, however now days its a bit different. Scroll through questions, how many are up-voted compared to down-voted? hmm? most people down vote because they do not understand the question, does not make the question a bad question though. If SO was a positive environment, people would encourage users (especially new ones) to write more questions buy either up-voting or not voting at all, did you see a problem with the question above? was it so bad that it should have got down voted?

Comment: @L.Gonzalez you have an if statement that has 4 `=` instead of 3.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, you were right, and I need glasses, and now we are back to our SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Comment: @L.Gonzalez I just posted another answer, take a look at it, I think it is what you want ;)

Comment: Sorry, but it *is* pretty funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to stay true to your homework, I kept the same format just fixed the issues.

here it is:

```
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
  var computerChoice = Math.random();


  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }

  console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

  var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
      if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "Paper wins!";
      } else {
        return "Paper looses!";
      }
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
      if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "Rock wins!";
      } else {
        return "Rock looses!";
      }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
      if (choice2 === "paper") {
        return "Scissors wins!";
      } else {
        return "Scissors looses!";
      }
    }


  }
  compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I just realized the way how curly brackets work thanks to your example.. (More like you did my homework for me :) anyhow, I realized that I can close every curly bracket after its respective if statement ends, and don't have to wait until the function ends :) thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You will find your debugging much easier if you

1. properly indent,
2. use braces for any but the simplest if statements

For example:

```
if (choice1 == choice2) return "tie";         /* simple 1-line if is ok */
if (choice1 == "rock") {
    if (choice2 == "scissors") {              /* more complex, always use braces */
        return "rock wins";                   /* always indent nicely */
    } else {
        return "paper wins";
    }
}
/* ... and so on ... */
```

Comment: What if **choice1** does not equal **choice2** and it equals **papper**?

Comment: yes, you would need two more analogous sections for `choice1 == "paper"`  and `choice1 == "scissors"` ...

Answer (score 1):

Always properly format your code. You are missing a bunch of `}` before the `else` statements. Always use semi-colons at the end of a line (no, you don't technically need to be it is extremely good practice).

Also, you need to watch your equals. You had one `====` instead of `===`

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
      if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
      } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
          return "paper wins";
        } else if {
          return "paper wins";
        } else {
          return "Paper wins";
        }    
      }
    }
}

compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

Comment: Check it here first, get it working then re-post ;) https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/c7ww2hmz/3/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith my goal isn't go fix all of the OPs problems with his code. It's to point out the obvious mistakes and the ones related to his question. I did fix the wrong `====` he had that was also in my answer.

Comment: I am willing to bet by the OP's question, that it is a she and not a he. the heart shape at the end gives it away lol

Answer (score 1):

Consider re-writing it in a little easier way.

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/c7ww2hmz/1/

```
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
  var computerChoice = Math.random();

  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
  alert("the computer picked " + computerChoice);
  if ((computerChoice === "rock" && userChoice === "papper") || (computerChoice === "papper" && userChoice === "scissors") || (computerChoice === "scissors" && userChoice === "rock")) {
    alert("you won");
  } else if (computerChoice == userChoice) {
    alert("It's a tie");
  } else {
    alert("you loose");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately there are a few things in your code that I have not even seen, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Here is it with your current code and my modifications https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/c7ww2hmz/4/

Comment: The thing that you haven't seen, is it the `&&` and `||`?

Comment: @L.Gonzalez here is a little quick tutorial on the `and's` and `or's` https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/c7ww2hmz/6/

Comment: Hahaha, yes, I have not seen the following: || I copied it from your comment, don't know how to get those lines and alert either, but I already knew that && kinda means "and" ?

Comment: @L.Gonzalez did you look at the fiddles in my comments?

Comment: I sure did thanks a lot, and that was a nice way of making a tutorial, seeing you code makes me want to keep learning. I just checked and I cannot change the way I am writing it, since it is a homework and is meant to have me go through the whole thing. Your ideas and the other guys ideas helped me, but now I get a syntax error: unexpected token =